# Correct implementation of a handler for handleSubmit [React]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to React and I don't understand why in many tutorials developers provide `submitHandler` with a local function meanwhile per to my knowledge, the `handleSubmit` in redux form already has `e.preventDefault` and there's no need to add some additional code.

Example of LoginPage from https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/09/16/react-redux-user-registration-and-login-tutorial-example

In this picture LoginPage has a local handler and it has state management and `e.preventDefault`

[image: Pic#1]

But in my form wrapped in redux form, I have a handler defined like this.
`LogInForm` is a PureComponent wrapped in redux form.

 From LogIn element I pass to LogInForm a handler defined without e.preventDefault

**Question#1**: Am I doing it wrong?
**Question#2**: Do I need to wrap LogIn in PureComponent or Component class?

This is my handler

```html
export default function (values) {
  console.log(`You submitted:\n\n${JSON.stringify(values, null, 2)}`);
}
```

[image: Pic#2]

[image: Pic#3]

Answer (score 0):

From `LogIn` component you are passing `onSubmit` prop to `LogInForm`. But in `LogInForm` component, you are trying to access `this.props.handleSubmit` which you are assigning to `onSubmit` of the `form`.

Instead pass `handleSubmit` prop to `LogInForm` from `LogIn` like this -

```
<LogInForm handleSubmit={LoginHandler}>
```